# Convert excel to xml

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I have one website (convert excel to xml). When i run on my machine everything's ok. but when i run my website through IIS. it have problem :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

below is my code :

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Request.QueryString["Name"]);
    string[] sheet = _ReadExcel.getSheetNames(filename);
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.Length; i++)
        {

        }
```

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please suggest to me some solution. Thanks

Comment: You need to post code and an error.

Comment: i have problem at ; Sheet.lenght.... why dont it appear in my machine ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sheet to an object before you call sheet.length on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Connect to Excel files
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
 System.Data.DataSet ds ;
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand ;
 MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='D:\\18.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
 MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
 MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Product");
 ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
 MyCommand.Fill(ds);
 MyConnection.Close();
 // Write to xml
 ds.WriteXml("Product.xml");
```

reference to [Generate Excel from XML and Generate XML from Excel](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371595/Generate-Excel-from-XML-and-Generate-XML-from-Exce#)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `filename` has correct path to your excel file or not.

if that path is correct. You need to grant permissions to the NETWORK SERVICE account to the folder you are trying to read or write.

not sure what is inside `_ReadExcel.getSheetNames` method, but it is returning 'null' value to your 'filename' input. You need to debug the application by attaching the IIS process in visual studio. then you can find the issue when run on IIS.

steps to debug on IIS :

- Debug->Attach To Process...
- Select the aspnet_wp.exe process from the list.
- If your running IIS > version 5 the process will be w3wp.exe, and there will be one for every app pool (so if you don't know which app pool your hitting, you'll need to attach to all of them)